# Accessing an object's array of objects attribute gives attribute error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I am having issues with accessing an object's attributes. The assignment itself is creating a number of algorithms comparing a number of objects' attributes, but I can't even get that far considering I haven't been able to access the attributes.

I have written a snippet of code that is similar to what I'm working with below. Where I'm having issues is when I try to access `list_of_things.items[0].attribute1`. I am trying to print simply to ensure that I'm accessing the item correctly, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(list_of_things.items[0].attribute1)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'attribute1'
```

Similar code is below:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attribute1='y', attribute2='n'):
        self.attribute1, self.attribute2 = attribute1, attribute2
    def give_a_thing(self):
        return self

class ThingOfThings:
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        self.items = items
    def get_thing(self, thing):
        self.items += [thing]

list_of_things = ThingOfThings()

one_thing = Thing()
for i in range(2):
    list_of_things.get_thing(one_thing.give_a_thing)
print(list_of_things.items[0].attribute1)
```

I am not able to change either class, but will be adding def's for my assignment.

Questions:

1. How do I access either attribute from the list_of_things?
2. How do I ensure I am accessing the attribute? (will print work or will it give the address)

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but the `[]` in the default argument for `items` is _the same instance_ for each time the constructor is called.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but likely to be the next bug that will need fixing, so yes, beware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the fundamental problem is exactly what the error message is implying:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'attribute1'
```

And that is because`items[0].attribute1` is trying to access `attribute`  on a *function object*, because`items[0]` is a function object. Note:

```
one_thing = Thing()
for i in range(2):
    list_of_things.get_thing(one_thing.give_a_thing)
```

Realize that `one_thing.give_a_thing` returns **the method itself**, you want to **call the method**:

```
one_thing = Thing()
for i in range(2):
    list_of_things.get_thing(one_thing.give_a_thing())
```

Aside from that, this code is incredibly strangely structured. Why is `give_a_thing` simply returning the object itself? That means your `list_of_things` is simply going to be a list containing multiple references to the *same object*.

You *probably* want something like

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, attribute1='y', attribute2='n'):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2


class ThingOfThings:
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        if items is None: # watch out for the mutable default argument
            items = []
        self.items = items
    def add_thing(self, thing): # use a better name
        self.items.append(thing) # don't create a needless intermediate, single-element list
```

Then simply:

```
list_of_things = ThingOfThings()

for _ in range(2): # style tip: use _ if iterator variable is not used
    list_of_things.add_thing(Thing()) # create *new* Thing each iteration

print(list_of_things.items[0].attribute1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Calling the method worked for me. As for the structure of the code, this was a very rough version of what the assignment actually has pre-defined. I didn't think too much when I made my version. Thanks again!